# Big Query Streaming API to overwrite rows using insertId

Tags: streaming, google-bigquery

When using the Big Query streaming api, and setting an `insertId` on each row, we can update (overwrite) rows by performing subsequent inserts with the same `insertId`.

This behaviour is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency), as only states:

> BigQuery uses the insertId property to de-duplicate your data on a best effort basis.

Will Big Query always overwrite rows with the same insertId?

Could this be potential be used to update data?

Answer (score 3):

Documentation: that's what the documentation says (or at least implies) by "deduplication": it assumes that data sent with the same `insertId` is the same, and thus will only insert one copy. However, note that this is best-effort, not guaranteed.

Overwrite: no, and due to a number of factors: it's only best-effort, you can't control which data will be kept (older or newer), and it only applies to data in the streaming buffer. Once data is committed, the de-duplication mechanism doesn't take effect anymore.

Comment: Not sure why they downvoted you, but have an upvote - that's the right answer.

Comment: Thanks @FelipeHoffa!

Comment: @FelipeHoffa and iustin this is rewording the documentation and making more assumptions, with nothing supporting them. 

As for overwrite this is not the behaviour we have found, we can overwrite the same row multiple times, in seperate requests.

How long is the streaming buffer? So far we have seen overwrites successfully occurring for 15+ minutes.

Comment: @j.davies - sorry if my reply was not clear. Let me try once more:

* the system's current implementation will overwrite the row as long as it is in the streaming buffer
* however, it is not a guaranteed behaviour that last-row-wins, so I personally wouldn't design a system around that
* and we don't have a guaranteed window for the streaming window (as far as I know)

Basically the only guarantee that BigQuery makes is that if you insert in short time frame the same row using the same `insertId`, you will only get one copy. But if you send different data, it does not provide guarantees.